# Angular 4 component library with ng-packagr

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, ng-packagr

I'm trying to build an angular 4 component library to share code across projects. To test the feature, I started by following this article.

https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

The library components build successfully but when I import this bundle into a test app, I get the following error.

`Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators`

I even tried importing polyfills in main.ts as mentioned in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2008, but no luck.

Is there any other way to get over this issue?

Thanks in advance!